# Repository DbContext and MyDBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I'm lost so need some help.

I'm using EF 4.2 and asp.net mvc3. I've Generic Reposiotry that work on DbContext , through IoC I've set up DbContext to be initialized as MyDBContext. It all works fine so far.

I'm using DbContext data member in my Repository class, so it has different APIs than that of MyDbContext. Am I doing it right?

thanks

Comment: What is `MyDBContext` and why do you have special type if your repository doesn't need it? Why your repository doesn't use your type?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka MyDBContext is the class that EF 4.2 offers which extends DbContext. And DbContext is what a few ppl last time encouraged me to use. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: No, it just means that your MyDBContext is only used for mapping definition.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka yes but I've a generic repository implementation and DbContext seems to be the only way to do it. do let me know if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If Im not using a unit of work pattern or services, here's how I do it

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
  private ICustomerRepository  _repository;
  public YourController(ICustomerRepository repository)
  {
     _repository = repository
  }

...
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
   private IContext _context;
  public CustomerRepository(IContext context)
  {
      _context = context;
  }

}
```

Your object graph is then built by your DI container. ENSURE your context is getting disposed on each request - this varies on configuration depending which DI container you use.

Comment: also I've a base class for controller which is using Services that operates on generic repositories. I hope this would help you guys guiding me better.

Comment: why would you be injecting a concrete implementation here (DbContext) rather than an interface? seems testing would be a bit harder that way. Are you injecting services or are you passing in your context to the services? personally, I like injecting to the controller and letting it build the object graph of all the dependencies down the line. If I want a service, I use an interface and inject the context into it. You can inject a concrete implementation (as you are doing) but it makes mocking/testing those controlers a bit tougher.